# função para diminuir o valor em 1 da tabela

Tags: php, mysqli, crud

eu queria fazer uma função onde a cada vez que ela seja chamada a tabela de parcelas ativa é diminuida em 1, segue o codigo que montei

```
     function quit() {
    $customer['parcelas'] = $customer['parcelas'] - 1;
   update('customers', $id, $customer);
```

porém, quando chamo a função no onclick ele simplesmente não faz nada, o que há de errado no código?

update: testei um outro tipo de codigo porém também não funcionou:

```
 function quit() {
         
         $sql ="UPDATE customers SET parcelas='" . $customer['parcelas'] ."'"; 
     
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Você pode fazer diretamente na query, desta forma:

```
function quit() {     
  $sql ="UPDATE customers SET parcelas = parcelas - 1";      
}
```

Comment: eu usei essa função em junção com uma variavel em sessão com o id para poder setar o where tambem porem nao funciona, eu dei um var_dump para ver se a variavel estava corretamente setada e estava normalmente, porem o codigo continuava sem funcionar

Comment: Qual o resultado do "dump" da $sql montada? Ex: var_dump($sql);

Comment: oi, desculpa a demora, ele dá uma string, não dá uma int

Comment: Olá, para te ajudar, preciso de mais detalhes. "não funciona" é bem amplo. Coloca sua função quit() de forma completa como ela está hoje. No seu exemplo só tem a variável $sql mas sem executar o comando no banco de dados.